# copy half the files to one place and other half to other c#

Tags: c#

if i have 4  files. and i want to move half of them to disc 1 and half of them to disc 2.

if im using the: 
`Directory.Move(source, destination)`
im guessing i can change to source by doing a foreach loop + an array or list,
but how could i change the destination after half the source files are transfered and then transfer the other half to the new destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] files = ... // create a list of files to be moved
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    var sourceFile = files[i];
    var destFile = string.Empty;
    if (i < files.Length / 2)
    {
        destFile = Path.Combine(@"c:\path1", Path.GetFileName(sourceFile));
    }
    else
    {
        destFile = Path.Combine(@"d:\path2", Path.GetFileName(sourceFile));
    }
    File.Move(sourceFile, destFile);
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's a lazy approach which doesn't require you to load all the file names in memory at once which could be used for example in conjunction with the [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"x:\sourcefilespath");
int i = 0;
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var destFile = Path.Combine(@"c:\path1", Path.GetFileName(file));
    if ((i++) % 2 != 0)
    {
        // alternate the destination
        destFile = Path.Combine(@"d:\path2", Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
    File.Move(sourceFile, destFile); 
}
```

Comment: or you could use `if (i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: @Hogan, yes this will also work, it's just that it would alternate, and and if there is a notion of order in the initial files collection might not be suitable.

Comment: @Darin: That approach would work with a plain enumeration though, so you wouldn't have to load the full list into memory - depends on OPs needs (after re-reading the question it seems like overkill I guess ;)

Comment: @BrokenGlass, sure, it's just that the notion of `half` doesn't make sense for an enumeration so I supposed the OP already have the list of files to copy in memory if he is talking about halves.

Comment: well half is "kinda" the same as "every other" though? (Not arguing your solution I think it's fine for OP)

Comment: @BrokenGlass, it depends, if there is a notion of order, then first half and second half wouldn't be the same if you getting those halves with alternation. Obviously there is no notion of order for files in a directory so it would be the same indeed.

Comment: i totally forgot about modulus.. DOH!

Comment: @BrokenGlass @Darin @Alex -- I guess my point is there is no difference between every other and first half vs second half.  Implies that perhaps the business rules need to be clearer -- why exactly are we splitting them and does content matter?

Comment: so umm, what if we up the ante, and say 3 files to 3 different paths?
and it doesnt matter which files goes where, just that they get there

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you would move the individual files instead.

Use a `Directory.GetFiles(source)` to get a list of files in the folder, get a `.Count()` of that and then loop through each file and move it.

```
public void MoveFilesToSplitDestination(string source, string destination1, string destination2)
{
    var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(source);
    int fileCount = fileList.Count();

    for(int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
    {
        string moveToDestinationPath = (i < fileCount/2) ? destination1 : destination2;
        fileList[i].MoveTo(moveToDestination);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rubikon= files.Count() / 2;
foreach (var file in files.Take(rubikon))
    file.Move(/* first destination */));
foreach (var file in files.Skip(rubikon))
    file.Move(/* second destination */));
```

Comment: Nice answer... now all we need is a function called `rubikon()` between the loops for the algorithm to cross.